# SQL Anywhere error - Function or column reference to 'Fraction' must also appear in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this simple SQL SELECT that summarizes by ProductID but I get this "must appear" error.

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, 
   Products.Qtty / Catalog.Fraction as Amount
FROM   Products, Catalog
WHERE  Catalog.ID = Products.ID
GROUP BY Products.ProductID
```

SQL requires me to put column Fraction into GROUP BY clause which I do not need. I just need to summarize by ProductID. How do I build correct SQL statement here?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question should include sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregate function:

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, 
   SUM(Products.Qtty) / SUM(Catalog.Fraction) as Amount
FROM Products
JOIN Catalog
  ON Catalog.ID = Products.ID
GROUP BY Products.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing division, so I might suspect that you want to divide *before* adding things up.  You should also use explicit `JOIN` syntax and table aliases:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, 
       SUM(p.Qtty / c.Fraction) as Amount
FROM Products p JOIN
     Catalog c
     ON c.ID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ProductID;
```